SELinux MLS enforcing, failt podman in user SELinux user_u
I have SELinux with policy MLS actived and in mode enforcing.
In the machine has podman installed. This works well as root. (scaling privileges with sudo)
[podman@vcs ~]$ podman ps -a
ERRO[0000] running `/usr/bin/newuidmap 1778 0 1001 1 1 589824 65536 65537 655360 65536 131073 720896 65536`: newuidmap: write to uid_map failed: Operation not permitted 
Error: cannot set up namespace using "/usr/bin/newuidmap": exit status 1

In the logs of SELinux not show nothing. I haven't feedback.
Podman needs move the user namespace and I understand that SELinux deny the permissions
Something understand because this is happening?
How to give permissions to podman of the linux user?
Thanks.
Greetings.
